# what is the best way to restrict services for certain users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, design-patterns, domainservices

**EDIT:** reworded and simplified question to be consise...

In my service layer I have something like

```
GetAllMessages(string userid);
```

I could have various types of users on my system like Clients / Supplier etc...

This service is only available to all types of users, however what is the best way to implement services only available to selected users e.g.

```
DeleteAllMessages(string userid); //client only
NewSupplierMessages(string userid); //supplier
```

Typically these methods will be in one class called **MessagesService**

NOTE: just to clarify, the user is loggedon and authenticated, however I am wondering if I should write my methods as such:

```
DeleteAllMessages(ClientUser user); //client only
NewSupplierMessages(SupplierUser userid); //supplier
```

Basically get the details of the user for every action and call methods in a more strongly typed manner...

**EDIT 2:**

Note my domain layer is in a seperate class library from my web app, a "client user" will be part of a "client", similarly a "supplier user" will be part of "supplier" - so if I wanted to query my service layer and call the correct code (i.e. retrieve the correct details) - I MUST pass in the user id or a strongly typed class of the user, I cannot see how having a contraint on a DTO object that represents who can access the service as incorrect/ brittle?

Other wise I will have something like this:

```
GetClientDetails();
```

The user is handled by asp.net so we know this action can be accessed by the user, however what if there are multiple clients? Surely then we must pass in some some of client id/ if I was to pass in user id I could get the client id from it...

Rather I would say my domain layer is incorrect seeing something like the above signature...

**EDIT 3:**
The only other alternative I could think off is, when the user authenticates, store the use in a class called UserSession inside the asp.net mvc application as a global state, then inject this using DI (ninject) into my domain service layer, therefore when my signatures can be

```
GetClientDetails();
```

The domain service class implementing this interface could be:

```
public class ClientService : IClientWorkerService
{

    private ISession _session;
    private IGenericRepo = _repo;
    public ClientService(IUserSession _session, IGenericRepo _repo)
    {
      this._session = _session;
      this._repo = _repo;
    }

    public ClientDetails GetClientDetails()
    {
      var loggedonuser = _session.GetUser();

      if(!loggedonuser.isClient())
        throw new NoAccessException()

      return _repo.Single<Client>(x=> x.ClientID == loggedonuser.ClientID);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please consider rewording your question in a more organized fashion.  Describe your problem, and then ask your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [MSDN: ASP.NET Authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx)

> Authorization determines whether an
>   identity should be granted access to a
>   specific resource. In ASP.NET, there
>   are two ways to authorize access to a
>   given resource:
>
> **File authorization**
>
> File
>   authorization is performed by the
>   FileAuthorizationModule. It checks the
>   access control list (ACL) of the .aspx
>   or .asmx handler file to determine
>   whether a user should have access to
>   the file. ACL permissions are verified
>   for the user's Windows identity (if
>   Windows authentication is enabled) or
>   for the Windows identity of the
>   ASP.NET process. For more information,
>   see ASP.NET Impersonation.
>
> **URL authorization**
>
> URL authorization
>   is performed by the
>   UrlAuthorizationModule, which maps
>   users and roles to URLs in ASP.NET
>   applications. This module can be used
>   to selectively allow or deny access to
>   arbitrary parts of an application
>   (typically directories) for specific
>   users or roles.

- [An Overview of Authentication and Authorization Options in ASP.NET](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140238/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031204-1.aspx)
- [Building Secure ASP.NET Applications: Authentication, Authorization, and Secure Communication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649362.aspx)
- [Role-based access control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control)
- [Custom role based Web Service access](https://stackoverflow.com/q/114888/277290)

Comment: I understand authentication- I will apply attributes/ filters to my controllers to prevent certain users from gaining access to my controllers, my question is more how I would organize my DomainService layer for the authenticated user

Comment: @Haroon, that is where Authorization comes into picture. You've authenticated the user, now you need to check if the user is authorized to perform a certain action. There are many ways of implementing it, though I think its better if you first grasp the idea of authorization being separate from authentication.

Comment: I am cool with authentication, before I implemented it using a ModelValueProvider when calling a controller, however I have changed my User table to make everyone part of one user table, hence I am wondering if I should stick to what I have outlined above in my edit above...

Comment: I wouldn't go with those signatures, it would make code a bit too brittle. I would recommend defining Roles for each user and then authorizing each request based upon those roles. For specific implementation you may want to see  [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/jigardesai/archive/2008/10/30/authorization-in-asp-net-mvc-using-xml-configuration.aspx).